# VueJS route is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to render my vue components inside the `router-view` tag. But it gives me an error

> TypeError: route is undefined

But I didn't use the word `route` in anywhere. This is my code.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <my-header></my-header>

    <router-view></router-view>

    <my-footer></my-footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

**outerroutes.js**

```
import welcome from './components/welcome.vue';
import insideSystem from './components/insideSystem.vue';
import forgotPassword from './components/forgotPassword.vue';

export const routes = [
  {path:'',component:welcome},
  {path:'/insideSystem',component:insideSystem},
  {path:'/forgotPassword',component:forgotPassword}

];
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import {routes} from './outerroutes';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode:'history'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  routes,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

I'm wondering where is this `route` came from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating a router instance as follows;

```
const router = new VueRouter({ 
    routes, 
    mode:'history' 
});
```

But you should inject the `router` instance to **router** option in the root vue instance not `routes`

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  //routes, not this
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In `outerroutes.js`:

`{path:'',component:welcome},`

There is nothing defined.  Try:

`{path:'/',component:welcome},`

Additionally, I'm not sure that you need the curly braces around `routes` in `main.js` at:

`import {routes} from './outerroutes';`

Comment: Also, the `route` is referring to one of the elements of your `routes` constant in `outerroutes.js`.

Comment: What I mean set {path:'/',component:welcome} is in default load the welcome component and load other components through programmatic navigation. But after I set {path:'/welcome',component:welcome} gives me the same error.

Comment: Did you try removing the curly braces from your import in `main.js`?

Comment: is there any restrictions to set file names? (insted of outerroutes.js route.js like wise )

Comment: No, you can pass in any filename as long as it exists.  I looked at one of my projects and found a difference that may be the problem.

Try importing the vue router from inside your `outerroutes.js` file:

   `import Vue from 'vue'`

    `import VueRouter from 'vue-router'`

Then, export an instantiation of the router: 

    Vue.use(VueRouter)
    export default new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        routes: [{
                path: '/',
               component: Welcome
            }];