# Uncaught TypeError: this.$route is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

So after multiple npm re-installs trying to get jscharting to play along the project finally builds but now when the localhost opens the following error is given in the DOM.

> Uncaught TypeError: this.$route is undefined

I have looked at a similar issue on SO :[VueJS route is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228042/vuejs-route-is-undefined) but it does not seem to be the same problem.

In addition the project was running fine until the jscharting fiasco was fixed.
I am also quite new to Vue.

With that said I was wondering if anyone can help with this.

**main.js**

```js
// VueJS
import Vue from 'vue'

// Ant Design Vue
import Antd from 'ant-design-vue';
import 'ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css';

Vue.use(Antd);

// Photoswipe Gallery
import Photoswipe from 'vue-pswipe'
Vue.use(Photoswipe)

// Template Layouts
import DefaultLayout from './layouts/Default.vue'
import DashboardLayout from './layouts/Dashboard.vue'
import DashboardRTLLayout from './layouts/DashboardRTL.vue'

// Adding template layouts to the vue components.
Vue.component("layout-default", DefaultLayout);
Vue.component("layout-dashboard", DashboardLayout);
Vue.component("layout-dashboard-rtl", DashboardRTLLayout);

import axios from 'axios';
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;

// Main application view
import App from './App.vue'

// Vue Router
import router from './router'

// App Styling
import './scss/app.scss';

//Setup API store for vuex
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

// Initialize Vue
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**App.vue**

```js
<!-- 
    This is the main page of the application, the layout component is used here,
    and the router-view is passed to it.
    Layout component is dynamically declared based on the layout for each route,
    specified in routes list router/index.js .
 -->

<template>
    <div id="app">
        <component :is="layout">
            <router-view />
        </component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default ({
        computed: {
            // Sets components name based on current route's specified layout, defaults to
            // <layout-default></layout-default> component.
            layout() {
                return "layout-" + ( this.$route.meta.layout || "default" ).toLowerCase() ;
            }
        },
    })
    
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

**router/index.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

let routes = [
    {
        // will match everything
        path: '*',
        component: () => import('../views/404.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        redirect: '/dashboards/',
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboards/',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        layout: "dashboard",
        // route level code-splitting
        // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
        // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
        meta: {
            title: 'Welcome to your Dashboard',
            sidebarMap: ['dashboards'],
            breadcrumbs: ['Dashboard', 'Home'],
        },
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ '../views/Dashboards/Default.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboards/crm',
        name: 'DashboardsCRM',
        layout: "dashboard",
        meta: {
            title: 'CRM',
            sidebarMap: ['dashboards'],
            breadcrumbs: ['Dashboards', 'CRM'],
        },
        component: () => import('../views/Dashboards/CRM.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/pages/alerts',
        name: 'Alerts',
        layout: "dashboard",
        meta: {
            layoutClass: 'dashboard',
            title: 'Alerts',
            sidebarMap: ['pages', 'alerts'],
            breadcrumbs: ['Pages', 'Alerts'],
        },
        component: () => import('../views/Alerts.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/pages/notifications',
        name: 'Notifications',
        layout: "dashboard",
        meta: {
            layoutClass: 'dashboard',
            title: 'Notifications',
            sidebarMap: ['pages', 'notifications'],
            breadcrumbs: ['Pages', 'Notifications'],
        },
        component: () => import('../views/Notifications.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/vendors/vendors-list',
        name: 'Vendors List',
        layout: "dashboard",
        meta: {
            title: 'Vendors List',
            sidebarMap: ['vendors', 'vendors-list'],
            breadcrumbs: ['Vendors', 'Vendors List'],
        },
        component: () => import('../views/Vendors/VendorsList.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/vendors/samplecall',
        name: 'Vendors List',
        layout: "dashboard",
        meta: {
            title: 'Vendors List',
            sidebarMap: ['vendors', 'samplecall'],
            breadcrumbs: ['Vendors', 'samplecall'],
        },
        component: () => import('../views/Vendors/SampleCall.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/homeowners/homeowners-list',
        name: 'Home Owners List',
        layout: "dashboard",
        meta: {
            title: 'Vendors List',
            sidebarMap: ['vendors', 'homeowners-list'],
            breadcrumbs: ['Vendors', 'homeowners List'],
        },
        component: () => import('../views/HomeOwners/HomeOwnerList.vue'),
    }, 
    {
        path: '/acc/acc-list',
        name: 'ACC List',
        layout: "dashboard",
        meta: {
            title: 'ACC List',
            sidebarMap: ['vendors', 'acc-list'],
            breadcrumbs: ['Vendors', 'acc List'],
        },
        component: () => import('../views/ACC/ACCList.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/vendors/newvendor',
        name: 'Vendors New',
        layout: "dashboard",
        meta: {
            title: 'New Vendor',
            sidebarMap: ['vendors', 'newvendor'],
            breadcrumbs: ['Vendors', 'New Vendor'],
        },
        component: () => import('../views/Vendors/NewVendor.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/vendors/editvendor/:id',
        name: 'Vendors Edit',
        layout: "dashboard",
        meta: {
            title: 'Edit Vendor',
            sidebarMap: ['vendors', 'editvendor'],
            breadcrumbs: ['Vendors', 'Edit Vendor'],
        },
        component: () => import('../views/Vendors/EditVendor.vue')
    },
    {
        path: '/layout',
        name: 'Layout',
        layout: "dashboard",
        component: () => import('../views/Layout.vue'),
    },
]

// Adding layout property from each route to the meta
// object so it can be accessed later.
function addLayoutToRoute( route, parentLayout = "default" )
{
    route.meta = route.meta || {} ;
    route.meta.layout = route.layout || parentLayout ;
    
    if( route.children )
    {
        route.children = route.children.map( ( childRoute ) => addLayoutToRoute( childRoute, route.meta.layout ) ) ;
    }
    return route ;
}

routes = routes.map( ( route ) => addLayoutToRoute( route ) ) ;

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'hash',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes,
    scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
        if ( to.hash ) {
            return {
                selector: to.hash,
                behavior: 'smooth',
            }
        }
        return {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth',
        }
    }
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it with the help of lodash get (you can also write it you self).
Do not get confused by my syntax I am using vue3, but with the known options api like vue2.

```
<template>
  <div class="app-container">
    <component :is="layout"
               :key="$route.name" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { get } from 'lodash';
import FullwidthLayout from '@/layouts/FullwidthLayout.vue';
import NarrowLayout from '@/layouts/NarrowLayout.vue';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'App',

    components: {
        FullwidthLayout,
        NarrowLayout,
    },

    computed: {
        layout(): string {
            const viewLayout = get(this.$route.meta, 'layout');
            if (viewLayout) {
                return `${viewLayout}`;
            }

            return 'FullwidthLayout';
        },
    },
});
</script>
```